# NodeJS - Express deployment to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

Index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const fs = require('fs');

const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'private',
    user: 'private',
    password: 'private',
    database: 'private'
})

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// GET
app.get('/api/get', (req, res) => {
    const sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM users";

    db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) => {res.send(result);});
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80, () => console.log(`running on port ${PORT}`))
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "devStart": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.4.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16"
  }
}
```

.gitignore

```
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js    
# testing
/coverage

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

Issue

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
```

Any ideas what might the issues be? I deploy my server folder straight to heroku using git. I tried restarting the app using 'heroku restart' but I can't get it to work. I have an add-on for ClearDB MYSQL which already has all the tables and columns.

Thank you

Update 1.1:

Heroku Build after pushing files:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXEz3.png)

More Images of logs after server builds.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XM0C.jpg

Comment: Do you have any more logs to share? Can you confirm that heroku is installing your dependencies?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of heroku installing everything after I push it with git

Comment: Feel free to check the server out, it should run on: https://foodeii.herokuapp.com/

Comment: The build logs look good. Do you have application logs before the crash?

Comment: @TrevorJohnson I have added logs after the server builds. The issue with one of them is I don't have 'node build/injdex.js' anywhere

Comment: This seems to be the issue:

`cannot find module /app/build/server.js`.

Is there a reference in your code somewhere to this file?